# Adding a loop for my school work

Tags: python

i currently need help with adding a loop that restarts the programme right after it asks the user if they would like to add another team instead of having the programme just end.

```
if rank == "expert": #If the user's rank is expert the programme will add an additional cost of 25 to the fee.
    if country == "EU": 
        print("Your fee is" + str(1.25*25*4)+"EUR")
    elif country == "US": 
        print("Your fee is" + str(1.50*25*4)+"USD")
    elif country == "AU":
        print("Your fee is" + str(2.00*25*4)+"AUD")
    else:
        print("Your fee is " + str(25*4)+"GBP")
else: #If the user's rank is anything other than expert such as beginner, the programme will charge the normal amount for the fee.
    if country == "EU":
        print("Your fee is" + str(1.25*10*4)+"EUR")
    elif country == "US": 
        print("Your fee is " + str(1.50*10*4)+"USD")
    elif country == "AU":
        print("Your fee is " + str(2.00*10*4)+"AUD")
    else:
        print("Your fee is " + str(10*4)+"GBP")

print("The names of your players are " +player1,player2,player3,player4)

print("Would you like to enter another team?") #Asks user if they would like to input another team.
answer = input() #Leaves a gap for the user to input.
answer = answer.lower() #Converts 'answer' into all lower case.
if answer == "yes": #Starts an 'if' statemant
    print("OK") #Displays 'OK' which tells the user the programme will continue.
else:
    print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: What conditions do you want to use for the loop? What kind of loop do you have in mind? What would cause the loop to end? What have you tried to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can put all of the code above in a `while True` loop, and in the very last line inside the else after printing, write `break`

So the start is

```
while True:
    if rank == "expert":
```

and the end code is

```
    if answer == "yes": #Starts an 'if' statemant
        print("OK") #Displays 'OK' which tells the user the programme will continue.
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

@mrfred489 's answer is good, but if your facing such problems it may help you a lot to learn a bit more of Python and programming languages in general ; google for Python beginner course :)